# Resize Foundation's Orbit Slider

Tags: resize, slider, zurb-foundation, orbit

Good Morning!

I'm working on a prototype and I would like to know the "proper" way to change the width of Foundation's Orbit Slider yet still keep it's responsiveness.

Currently - I had changed the width of the slider container to a smaller percentage (73%) - but when viewed at mobile size, it just doesn't seem quite right. Not to mention the arrows have floated upwards and I'd rather not hack some css to get them positioned correctly.

Orbit CSS: http://naivestudio.net/win-prototype/prototype/orbit.php (put on separate page just for this question - changes will be made in the app.css file)

HTML in Index Page - Note the video is outside of the slider, but I will have it floated next to it in the header container.

```
<div id="headcontain" class="row">
    <div id="featured">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide5">
    </div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/235x300&text=Video">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<!-- Include Orbit -->
<script src="foundation/javascripts/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window).load(function() {
   $("#featured").orbit( { 
   timer: false
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

the proper way to resize an orbit slider is to wrap it in a div with a class specifying how many columns you'd like it to stretch across. By changing the number of columns the container stretches across, the framework will then automatically resize the slider. If you're using foundation 4 or greater you'll need to use their new syntax of "large-(#)" or "small-(#)" when specifying the number of columns.

You had said that on small resolution it looked incorrect, if you're using Foundation 4+ you can use a combination of both large and small size calls to affect how it appears on both large and small resolutions; the following example will span twelve columns on a large resolution and only span 3 columns when you reach a smaller resolution.

### Situational Resolution Sizing Example for Foundation 4+:

```
<div class="large-12 small-3 columns">
```

### Full Example for Foundation 4+:

```
<div id="headcontain" class="row">
    <div class="large-12 small-3 columns">
        <div id="featured">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide1">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide2">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide5">
        </div><!--/featured-->
        <img src="http://placehold.it/235x300&text=Video">
    </div><!--/large12-->
</div><!--/headcontain-->
```

### Full Example for Foundation 3-:

```
<div id="headcontain" class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div id="featured">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide1">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide2">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/700x300&text=Slide5">
        </div><!--/featured-->
        <img src="http://placehold.it/235x300&text=Video">
    </div><!--/twelveColumns-->
</div><!--/headcontain-->
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As of v6.5.3 it appears that this still hasn't been resolved BUT it looks like there will be fix in v7. More info hero on [Github](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7815).